# Making changes to data in dataTable from database Table

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I am trying to do a temporary table that will hold on to the changes made until the user clicks on a save button which will submit all the changes on the datatable to the database table. For this example, my temp datatable "lineTable" is the one submitting changes to the database Table "NaftaLineTable". Currently my code is set to submit changes straight to the database, no save button clicked, and I'm not sure how to work it to just make the changes to the temp datatable.
example code:

```
Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand("UPDATE NAFTALineTable SET BoxQuantity = NAFTALineTable.BoxQuantity + (Select COALESCE(sum(ShipmentLineTable.LineBoxes),0) FROM ShipmentLineTable WHERE ShipmentNumber = 1111", con)
If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open()
              cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
               con.Close()
```

I want to do this update command on my temp datatable instead of the database table. I tried researching but not finding what I'm looking for. If you need to understand what my query is doing it's taking the quantity of boxes from  NAFTalineTable, updating it to equal the quantity of boxes from ShipmentLineTable + the quantity of boxes from the NAFTALineTable where ShipmentNumber is 1111.

psuedocode for what I want, I know the syntax is wrong that's what I don't understand how to do:

```
Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand("Select COALESCE(sum(ShipmentLineTable.LineBoxes),0) FROM ShipmentLineTable WHERE ShipmentNumber = 1111", con)
 If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open()
          lineTable.Column("BoxQuantity").("Shipment"=1111) += cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
          con.Close()
```

Comment: Looks like strongly-typed dataset/datatable does exactly what you want. Your first sentence is a description of exactly that.

Comment: @PeterG what do you mean by strongly-typed? Manually coding it? Because I am doing so if thats what you meant then you didn't read my question thoroughly. I'm trying to figure out how to do the part where I am attempting my "psuedocode" at the end of my question.

Comment: I mean the ADO.Net Strongly-typed dataset and associated components - datatable, tableadapter, etc. Bear in mind I have no idea what you are trying to achieve; just that your first sentence describes how those components work (- with the proviso that they are normally specific to each user rather than a temp table in the db, which might, for all I know, be a key element in what you're aiming at.)

Comment: A regular datatable will store any number of adds, changes and deletes and nothing goes to the database until you update

Comment: Yep, thanks, good catch @plutonix, I didn't mean to imply the weekly-typed variant won't do the job; I was thinking perhaps the OP might find strongly-typed one, complete with the designer etc more familiar as it's more like the SSMS table designer.

Comment: You could also let users re-review the changes before they are sent to the db.